# Question about book reports

Tags: learning

I are writing a book report and the main person's name isn't revealed. How do I write about this?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Could you give us more ideas about your problem? I guess that your book report is an assignment: to show that you have read the book and understand what you read well enough. Another guess: you probably don't know how to write about the main characters because the writer doesn't mention their names. In that case, you can call them the same way that the writer calls them, for example, the old man, the little girl, the grasshopper, and so on.

Comment: The story is told in first person, so the name is never said, but I find it difficult to write about a story in first person, the report is an assignment yes

Comment: One option would be to refer to this person as ***the unnamed narrator***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider referring to the narrator as the *protagonist* if he or she is the leading character.